# linux architecture environment variable or definition?

Tags: linux, bash, architecture

I'm creating my own rpm files. Now I'm writing a bash script that will put these rpm's automatically in the repository structure:

```
distribution/arch/rpm
```

eg:

```
openSUSE13.1/i586/product-0.1.0-0.i586.rpm
```

I have found that in the `/etc/os-release` file I can find the name of the distribution I have etc; but not my architecture. So how do I get the architecture of my computer? I know I could eventually parse it from the rpm name (which looks like this: `product-0.1.0-0.i586.rpm`), but probably there is some file describing my computer architecture that would give me `i586` easily?

**EDIT** the rpm's I produce have the i586 architecture in their name. However:

- `uname -m` gives me i686
- `uname -i` gives me i386

Comment: Not an answer, but some ideas. On my machine, `/usr/lib/rpm/macros` defines `%_arch` as `x86_64`; you might also look at the `--target` option to `rpmbuild`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Jord I found this line in the file `/usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc`:

```
buildarchtranslate: i686: i586
```

so apparently it is rpmbuild that does a translation from my "uname -m" architecture i686 to i586. So theoretically it would be possible to use uname -m and look in the rpmrc file for a translation, but that would be very laborious.

**in short**
parsing the name of the rpm that was produced is the most effective way to get the architecture. No macro or variable seems to be defined that matches the one produced by rpmbuild (since a translation step is included)